ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'photo_app.wsgi'
I'm trying to deploy my Django application using Gunicorn and systemd on an Ubuntu server. However, the Gunicorn service fails to start with the following error.
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'photo_app.wsgi'
**
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '*.wsgi'.](https://i.sstatic.net/yNykpB0w.png)
In my folder  the passport_photo_maker module exists and contains a wsgi.py file.
#gunicorn.service
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=gopikumarkaushik9065
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/gopikumarkaushik9065/Passport-Size-Photo-Maker
ExecStart=/home/gopikumarkaushik9065/Passport-Size-Photo-Maker/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/gopikumarkaushik9065/Passport-Size-Photo-Maker/gunicorn.sock passport_photo_maker.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

if there is no mention of photo_app.wsgi in gunicorn.service then why error is occuring?
#wsgi.py
"""
WSGI config for passport_photo_maker project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'passport_photo_maker.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()

settings.py
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ':) security key'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'photo_app'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'passport_photo_maker.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'passport_photo_maker.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'photo_appstatic'),
]

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'


Can you share your application wsgi file and settings.py file

Thank you for your help, Bhaiya. I have updated the question accordingly. You can see the wsgi.py and settings.py code in the question itself.

It was nice to hear Bhaiya after long time. Issue seems to be with local configuration. What you can do to segregate the issue just run the application directly with unicorn configuration and check is there any error in gunicorn logs. command : /home/gopikumarkaushik9065/Passport-Size-Photo-Maker/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/gopikumarkaushik9065/Passport-Size-Photo-Maker/gunicorn.sock /home/gopikumarkaushik9065/Passport-Size-Photo-Maker/passport_photo_maker.wsgi:application
